# What is execution order of overriding in Java?

Tags: jvm, overriding

```
Parent instance = new Child();
instance.method();
```

When we call method, JVM will find child method directly or find parent class firstly, find child, find method, or some other sequence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Comment: @ShanthaKumara It seems no answers. Could you just tell me whether the JVM will find the method in subclass directly depend on the actual implemented class?

Comment: The `method()` is first searched in the Child then Parent. In other words, JVM starts from most specific implementation to generic implementation to find the `method()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I may add a more comprehensive example:

```java
class Parent {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Child");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.print();
    }
}
```

This program will print `Hello from Child`. Although we instantiate the `Child` via the `Parent`, Java will look for the "nearest" implementation of `print()`, starting from the child.